# React native wix/react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

Having some issues with [this navigation library](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation). 
 
I see that all components independent, but i need to have like HOC on top of all screens. 
For example if i have no connection i would like to show only one screen and if connection available - show current tab based app

How do i can do this?

Thanks for any ideas.

***Register components code***

```
const registerScreens = (appType, store) => {
  switch (appType) {
    case appTypes.ROOT_APP: {
      Navigation.registerComponent(screens.APP, () => App, store, ApolloProvider, { client });
      break;
    }
    case appTypes.SINGLE_BASED_APP:
      Navigation.registerComponent(screens.ONBOARDING, () => OnboardingContainer, store, ApolloProvider, { client });
      break;
    case appTypes.TAB_BASED_APP:
      // App Screens
      Navigation.registerComponent(screens.DISCOVER, () => DiscoverContainer, store, ApolloProvider, { client });
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error('appType is not defined.');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need NetInfo API in React native for checking connection status. And use Navigation of react-native-navigation to move to the right screen - either single screen app or tab based app.

```
NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then((connectionInfo) => {
  if (connectionInfo.type === 'none') {
    Navigation.startSingleScreenApp(params);
  } else {
    Navigation.startTabBasedApp(params);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help! 

But what if i will go to background mode and then resume my app but without connection? 
Probably i should wrap all my component with a HOC and listen for changes right?

Comment: You could watch for AppState change and within that callback, call the above startup code.